# My app targets Android 13 but I still get the warning message in the console saying that: the App must target Android 13 (API level 33) or higher

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I received a warning message in the console and by email saying that one of my apps must target Android 13 (API level 33) otherwise I won't be able to update it after August 31st.

The problem is that my app is already targeting Android 13 and has been since the beginning of the year. In my code, I set the targetSDK and compileSDK to 33: `targetSdkVersion 33` `compileSdkVersion 33`.

I then updated all the versions in the test channels (Internal, Closed and Open testing) so that they all target SDK level 33 and again the production version. But the warning persists. What bothers me is that even in the "Releases Overview" section, it says that the app does indeed target SDK level 33.

[image: Release information in the releases overview section]

However, there's a new app I launched this year that also targets SDK level 33 and doesn't get this warning.

So I created a new project on my computer and replaced some of its elements with those of the app folder that receives the warning (key, package name, signature, google services files and packages...). So it's as if the app code has just changed folder, but now has a build.grade and AndroidManifest file written with the new features. After that, I did the update again.

Despite all this, the warning still appears in the console.

[image]

[image]

Can you please advise me? Or does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you press `View details` and after `View affacted app bundles`, does it show you the problematic build?

Comment: Thank you @PeterKoltai for your comment. But after clicking on `View details` in the Policy Status section, there is no link or button named `View affacted app bundles`.  I'll edit my question to add a screenshot of the page that comes after `View details`.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/migration) instructions and migrate your codebase to support the new Android API target 33.